# How to split list into equal sublists with the last sublist made up from the first possible elements of the list

Tags: python, python-2.7, list

I want to split a list into sub-lists of a specified length.  If the last chunk is not of the specified length, it will be augmented from the first element(s) of the list.

The below Python program produces equal sub-lists except for the last chunk.

```
def split_list(the_list, chunk_size):
    result_list = []
    while the_list:
        result_list.append(the_list[:chunk_size])
            the_list = the_list[chunk_size:]

    return result_list

a_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

print split_list(a_list, 3)
```

Output:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10]]
```

**I want something like this:**

```
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10, 1, 2]]
```

Comment: This is all about lists. Array means something different in Python. Please fix title and tags

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check to see whether you're going to be short in the last list chunk.  If so, add exactly the needed quantity of elements, duplicated form the front of the list.

```
def split_list(the_list, chunk_size):
    result_list = []
    short = len(the_list) % chunk_size
    if short:
        # Add wrap-around elements from front of the_list
        the_list.extend(the_list[:chunk_size-short])

    while the_list:
        result_list.append(the_list[:chunk_size])
        the_list = the_list[chunk_size:]

    return result_list

a_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

print(split_list(a_list, 3))
```

Output:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10, 1, 2]]
```

Answer (score 3):

Let's try a generator-based solution using `itertools.cycle` and `islice`:

```
from itertools import cycle, islice         
def split_list(lst, n):    
     it = cycle(lst)
     for i in range(len(lst) // n + len(lst) % n):
         yield list(islice(it, n))
```

Call the function like this:

```
>>> a_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
>>> list(split_list(a_list, 3))
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10, 1, 2]]
```

I personally prefer a generator here because the chunks are yielded one at a time, efficiently. If you want everything at once, you call `list()` on the result (like I've done).

Comment: I have this error from python 2: "NameError: name 'chunk' is not defined"

Comment: @DanielJames I made a mistake with the function name, which I just corrected.

Comment: damn and to think I was about to demonstrate a fix with floor division and modulus, my itertools needs so much work

Comment: Base on your change, this is what I have: [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]. Please check if there is a mix up somewhere.

Comment: @DanielJames Oops, my mistake. Accidentally removed something I shouldn't have in an earlier edit. Check again

Comment: @coldspeed I appreciate your speedy response, It works like I want.

Comment: @DanielJames Thanks. If the answer solved your problem, please mark it accepted. You can only mark one as accepted, however.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use a list comprehension and then add part of the start of the list to the final group if needed.

```
def split_list(the_list, chunk_size):
    chunks = [the_list[i:i+chunk_size] for i in range(0, len(the_list), chunk_size)]
    chunks[-1] += the_list[:(chunk_size - len(the_list)) % chunk_size]
    return chunks
```